# Java program to reverse a string with certain pattern

Tags: java, reverse

What logic should be used to get the output in that pattern?
In pattern, each number represents the position of the word given in the string.

```
Example 1: 
i/p:           A dead fox found in the forest
o/p:         tserof ni eht dnuof xof A daed
pattern        7    5   6    4    3  1   2

Example 2:
i/p:            A dead fox found in the deep forest
o/p:           tserof eht peed ni dnuof daed xof A
                8      6   7   5     4    2   3  1
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Have you tried to do something yourself? Do you have any code?

Comment: Use a Scanner to read a sentence, read word indexes, and output the words reversed in the index order.  Break your problem up into tiny steps that you can code.  If you get stuck in a specific line of code, then that might make a better Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

This would be one function to reverse the strings.

```java
public static String reverseString(String str)
{
    return new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
}
```

To perform the other part as to your patterns:

```java
String[] arrayWithStrings = new String[]{"A", "dead", "fox", "found", "in", "the", "forest"};
int[] pattern = new int[]{7, 5, 6, 4, 3, 1, 2};

for (int i : pattern)
{
    System.out.println(reverseString(arrayWithStrings[i - 1]));
}
```

This was pretty trivial since the patterns show the position of the word in a sentence.
If you have to parse a whole Sentence and not an `array[]`. Then you could get that sentence as string and use `split(" ")` to get an array out of it.

Still, just getting things solved here on SO is very discouraged. Do something yourself, try!